# What is a Archival Tumor Tissue ? For What Purpose is it collected?

Tags: cancer, pharmacology, medicine, clinical-trial

Over the course of Conducting trials various tissue and tumor samples are collected  from the patients.

One such sample is the Archival Tumor Tissue. 
Could someone kindly clarify what is the meaning of the term archival tumor?, and what data is gleaned from it.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? A Google search pulls up many hits. We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question & explicitly indicate research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, & it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a tumor is removed from a patient, it is usually send to the pathology the make sure that it has been excised completely to make sure there are no residues. Often this tumor is also used to analyze the mutation status of the tumor to determine, which further treatment is possible. For example, this is routinely done for melanoma where the mutation status excludes some drugs for further treatment.

Afterwards these tumors are important material for the scientific tumor research to isolate fresh cell lines or analyze them further. Parts of it are usually stored either frozen or as formalin fixed tissue to build tissue banks. These can be used for later research on this type of tumor and have a high value.

These tissues can then be cut and stained with antibodies or used for nucleic acid extraction (either DNA or RNA) or to test new ideas or methods which where not available to the time when the samples was archived.

Another famous case (although not from tumors) are tissues samples which have been archived from people deceased from the spanish flu in 1918, where parts of the virus was reconstructed using these samples decades later.